# renaming inputs with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing

I have inputs with names like this

```
  <textarea type="text" name="featured[items][58252][hpsummary]" cols="50" class="limit20_120">asdfasdfasfasfdsadfasdfaasdfasfdasfasfasdf</textarea>
```

and I need to renumber the items I can loop through all the inputs no problem, but I am stuck on how to re number them so that the above would then then be 1 instead of 58252

```
  <textarea type="text" name="featured[items][1][hpsummary]" cols="50" class="limit20_120">asdfasdfasfasfdsadfasdfaasdfasfdasfasfasdf</textarea>
```

i can numerate just not sure how to parse it

I was thinking of just splitting the string but i'm not sure if I could use an regex so that I don't have to worry if there are more items on the end or if there is a better way

Comment: I'll just leave this here. Again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @Cfreak i'm not trying to parse the html just the name string

Comment: Maybe use serialize() and post() to send the input names (and values) to the server, parse and re-create them there, then use the results of the post() to replace the inputs?

Comment: @Cfreak while I was thinking of the same comment this question is only about the stuff *inside* the name attribute, which is sufficiently regular...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$('.limit20_120').each(function(i){
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\d+/, i+1);
});
```

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/4RUxS/

Comment: that would be fine but hpsummary could be anything and more may follow

Comment: if there are number further down stream wouldn't that change them as well ?

Comment: It's a little more verbose, but if you need to restrict the replacement, just add more of the name to the regex, i.e. `this.name.replace(/^featured\[items\]\[\d+\]/, 'featured[items]['+(i+1)+']');`